# Laravel Notification markasread does no update the notification table

Tags: laravel, notifications

If I missed an easy part of whole thing forgive. 
I am observing a strange behavior of Laravel Notifications between my local development and my server on Bluehost. On my PC it runs version 5.5 and Bluehost 5.4

I set the database notification and successfully can get them as expected.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" role="menu"  onclick="markPostAsRead({{count(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications)}})">
   <li>
   @forelse (auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
          @include('layouts.notifications.'.snake_case(class_basename($notification->type)))
        @empty
        <strong>No notification</strong>
        @endforelse
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Then when the user click it triggers a javascript to get the route to update the read_at column in my notification table in the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
 function markPostAsRead(countofNotification){
    if(countofNotification !== '0')
      $.get('/markasread');
 }
</script>
```

Following is the route

```
 Route::get('/markasread',function(){
        auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->first()->markAsRead();
   });
```

Everything went as expected on my local environment.

Once uploaded with all migrations in place, the notifications are shown as expected. However when the user clicks the notification the table does not update. 
I checked that the js is working with some alerts on both server and local environment. But I do not understand why the table does not update on my server side.

If you could give me one hint it will really help me.

The notification html is a follows

```
<div class="top_nav">
  <div class="nav_menu">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav toggle">
        <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown"  >
          <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle info-number" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
            <span class="badge bg-green">{{count(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications)}}</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list"  id="notification" role="menu"  onclick="markPostAsRead({{count(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications)}})">
            <li>
              @forelse (auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
              @include('layouts.notifications.'.snake_case(class_basename($notification->type)))
              @empty
              <strong>No Unread Notification</strong>
              @endforelse
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>.
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" > 
  var mynotificationcount;
  function markPostAsRead(countofNotification){
   mynotificationcount= countofNotification;
 }

 $('#notification').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = this.href;
  if(mynotificationcount !== '0') {
    $.get('/markasread');
  } else {
    window.location.href = href;
  }
});
</script>
```

Thanks,

Comment: do you see any errors in the Network tab of your browser dev tools when the jquery function sends the get request to /markasread or is it coming back 200?

Comment: @Giovanni, thank you. Yes the status is 200

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@N69S
Thank you very much.

I updated the java script a little bit to get around. I named the route and set as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
  var mynotificationcount;
  function markPostAsRead(countofNotification){
   mynotificationcount= countofNotification;
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" > 
    $('#notification a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        var url = "{{route('markasread')}}";
        if(mynotificationcount !== '0') {
           $.get(url).always(function(){window.location.href = href;});
          // window.location.href="{{ route('markasread') }}";
        } else {
            window.location.href = href;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: since the answer i provided had more details on the reason why it works, why not set it as the accepted answer ?

Comment: I think I set it

Answer (score 1):

The redirection of the page is faster than the Ajax request to update the table.

you should make the click event trigger the ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
    $('#notification a').on('click', function(e){
        if(countofNotification !== '0') {
            $.get('/markasread');
        }
    });
</script>
```

if that doesnt work, you will need something more complicated like

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
    $('#notification a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        if(countofNotification !== '0') {
            $.get('/markasread')->always(function(){window.location.href = href;});
        } else {
            window.location.href = href;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. could you help the on how I should change the dropdown side. I the the id='notification' but it does not got through.

Comment: @Adjeiinfo put your notification list's HTML on your question so i can help you

Comment: can you put the rendered HTML starting from the `<ul class="dropdown-menu`

Comment: <ul class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list"  id="notification" role="menu"  onclick="markPostAsRead(1)">
            <li>
                            <a  href="http://localhost.test/post/9">
<strong>Owner </strong>Closed the ticket<strong> 325</strong>
</a>                          </li>
          </ul>

Comment: I added in the comment. Thank you for your time

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have some rooting problems but I will do it. Your insights was really helpful. After I solve the route problem I will mark it as the answer. I works fine on localhost.